# Dynamically created Select element is different in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

There is some strangeness while I create in JavaScript Select element:

```
var items = {"3":"Three","1":"One","2":"Two"};
var elem = document.createElement("select");

for ( var key in items) {
    var ov = document.createElement("option");
    ov.value = key; 
    ov.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[key]))
    elem.appendChild(ov);
}

document.getElementById('someDiv').appendChild(elem);
```

FF create Select element with initial elements order (Three, One, Two). 
Chrome sorts elements by key and output in next way (One, Two, Three).

Why this happen? And how prevent sorting in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for … in` statement iterates over an object in an unpredictable order. As MDC [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> A `for...in` loop iterates over the
>   properties of an object in an
>   arbitrary order (see the [delete
>   operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator#Cross-browser_issues)
>   for more on why one cannot depend on
>   the seeming orderliness of iteration,
>   at least in a cross-browser setting).

You'd better use an array of objects and use an ordinary `for` loop to keep the specified order, like:

```
var items = [{"3":"Three"}, {"1":"One"}, {"2":"Two"}];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++}
    /* etc */ ;
```

Just a side note: when iterating over object using `for … in`, you really should use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check whether it is an inherited property or not, otherwise you might include inherited properties in your `select` box.

Comment: Thanks! Probably the problem is in not cross-browser behavior of var … in statement